# python create a set / dict / list and the sum of its values from a single list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I wonder if two list comprehensions are needed to return the ordered pair of a set / dict / list and the sum of the values in the set / dict / list. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
>>> l = ['abc', 'd', 'efgh', 'ij']
>>> {i: len(i) for i in l}, sum(len(i) for i in l)
({'efgh': 4, 'abc': 3, 'ij': 2, 'd': 1}, 10)
```

Is there a better / more pythonic way to write this than with duplicate `for i in l` comprehensions?

UPDATE:

I asked this question because I was thinking of the best way to write a particular `lambda`; i.e.

```
>>> l = ['abc', 'd', 'efgh', 'ij']
>>> dict_value = lambda l: ({i: len(i) for i in l}, sum(len(i) for i in l))
>>> dict_value(l)
({'efgh': 4, 'abc': 3, 'ij': 2, 'd': 1}, 10)
```

I asked this question because I am not using `len()` to calculate the value I want, but rather a expensive calculation. The point below about the for-loop does solve the problem if I define a secondary method rather than a lambda to do work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, or you just use a regular loop:

```
d, s = {}, 0
for i in l:
    d[i] = len(i)
    s += len(i)
```

A list or set or dictionary comprehension should be used to create one object; avoid trying to create side effects too. And don't discount the utility of a regular loop!

Also, don't hesitate to use a function instead of a lambda:

```
def as_dict_and_total(l):
    d, s = {}, 0
    for i in l:
        d[i] = len(i)
        s += len(i)
    return d, s
```

Comment: The issue with this is that it doesn't take advantage of the speed of list comprehensions, which are substantially faster than regular loops.

Comment: @qaphla: Not *that* much faster, and one loop is better than 2.

Comment: Most tests that I've run give list comprehensions being more than twice as fast as standard for loops, but I'm sure this varies by operation, and so won't argue the point.

Comment: @Martijn This is true. But that isn't a list comprehension, just a `for` loop.

Comment: @qaphla: that depends entirely on what you are doing. Most of that time goes into the list object resizing, and the `.append()` attribute lookup. Both can be worked around, to a certain extend.

Answer (score 3):

You could precompute the lengths. I think it is cleaner to look at:

```
>>> l = ['abc', 'd', 'efgh', 'ij']
>>> llen = [len(i) for i in l]
>>> dict(zip(l,llen)), sum(llen)
({'abc': 3, 'd': 1, 'efgh': 4, 'ij': 2}, 10)
```

Comment: Note that string lengths are just a simple attribute lookup on the strings; this doesn't buy you much of any speed.

Comment: I know, but I don't think the OP is really looking for speed. Actually I don't understand most of the time what people mean by 'pythonic' ways these days. I think they are usually just looking for shorter or cleaner-looking code, no matter what is happening under the hood.

Comment: @HariShankar Re: 'more pythonic' .. I get your point. I think speed is very much part of the answer. Shouldn't anyone be able to write some readibility into their code?

Comment: I agree, readability should be the first priority in most cases. But the problem is that it is usually subjective.